# perform delete or update on unique violation in postgres

Tags: postgresql, unique, sql-delete, unique-constraint

On Unique_violation exception how to update or delete the row which raised the exception

*table code and insert*

```
create table test
(
id serial not null,
str character varying NOT NULL,
is_dup boolean DEFAULT false,
CONSTRAINT test_str_unq UNIQUE (str)
);

INSERT INTO test(str) VALUES ('apple'),('giant'),('company'),('ap*p*le');
```

*Function*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rem_chars()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
begin 
update test set str=replace(str,'*','');
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
--what to do here to delete the row which raised exception or
--to update the is_dup=true to that row 
end;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION rem_chars() OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do? DELETE or UPDATE in the exception?

Comment: @ahwnn Anyone is ok update or delete.I know the syntax but don't know how to apply that on that particular row using where clause or Is there something similar to last_insert_id that returns the id of row which raised exception.

Comment: you should have had that explanation in the question right from the start. I don't think you can find out which row caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

-- this will show you all the potential key collisions

```
SELECT a.id, a.str, b.id , b.str
FROM test a, test b
WHERE a.str = replace(b.str,'*','')
AND a.id < b.id;
```

-- this will delete them

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE id IN (
  SELECT b.id
  FROM test a, test b
  WHERE a.str = replace(b.str,'*','')
  AND a.id < b.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to do this in two steps:

```
UPDATE test 
  SET str = replace(str,'*','')
  WHERE str NOT IN (SELECT replace(str,'*','') FROM test);

UPDATE test
  SET is_dup = true
  WHERE str IN (SELECT replace(str,'*','') FROM test);
```

At least I can't think of a more efficient way.